# Eliminar tablas vacía con macro (Excel Vba)

Tags: vba, ms-word

Cordial saludo

Necesito eliminar tablas vacías mientras la primera fila de cada tabla no tengo información. He probado la siguiente macro pero solo funciona para una fila en especifico (la asignada en la macro). La idea es que las elimine todas. Las tablas que estoy manejando son de 5 filas.

Adjunto macro:

```
Sub Tabla()
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Select
Selection.MoveLeft

 If IsNumeric(Selection) = False And _
    Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = True _
 Then Selection.Rows.Delete

End Sub
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Jhon, por lo que veo en el código hablas de Word, deberías cambiar la etiqueta de excel por la de Word ya que quizá consigas más ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración.

Answer (score 0):

No tengo mucha idea de Word, pero con la experiencia de Excel, necesitas un bucle que recorra todas las tablas del documento.

Para ello necesitas declarar una variable del tipo `Table` y luego un bucle que recorra todas las que haya en el documento tal que así, `For Each Table in ThisDocument.Tables` (por cada tabla en las tablas de este documento).

He intentado aplicar tu lógica en esto, pero no sé si funcionará así, si no deberías cambiar el código que hay dentro del `With Tablas` que es el encargado de comprobar y eliminar, lo demás debería funcionar.

```
Option Explicit
Sub EliminarTablas()

    Dim Tablas As Table

    For Each Tablas In ThisDocument.Tables
        With Tablas
            If Not IsNumeric(.Cell(1, 1)) And .Cells(1, 1).Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
                .Cell(1, 1).Row.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next Tablas

End Sub
```

Comment: Cordial saludo. He implementado este código, funciona pero el problema radica cuando en la primera fila de las tablas hay reglas(Si...entonces...si) entonces la toma como fila llena eliminado el resto de filas menos esa.

Comment: Me he limitado a copiar tu lógica, siento no poder ayudarte más, pero nunca he utilizado VBA en word. si quieres eliminar la tabla entera, por qué no utilizas `Tablas.Delete`? creo que eso debería eliminarla por completo @JhonMartinez

Comment: Muchas gracias por los aportes.

Answer (score 0):

Cordial saludo.

He implementado este código, funciona pero el problema radica cuando en la primera fila de las tablas hay uso de  reglas(Si...entonces...si) entonces la toma como fila llena eliminado el resto de filas menos esa.

```
Sub eliminar_tablas()

Dim fila As Row
' hacemos un recorrido por todas las filas del documento
For Each fila In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows
' Seleccionamos el texto de la primera celda de la fila
With fila.Cells(1).Range.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
' Si la celda esta vacía borramos la fila
 If .Text = "" Then
 fila.Delete
 End If
End With
Next fila

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Según he podido encontrar, la idea es buscar unos caracteres en el contenido de la celda de cada fila para detectar que la celda vacía consta de una marca de párrafo seguida de Chr(7).

```
Sub eliminar_tablas()

    Dim fila As Row
    ' hacemos un recorrido por todas las filas del documento
    For Each fila In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows
        ' Seleccionamos el texto de la primera celda de la fila
        With fila.Cells(1).Range.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
        ' Si la celda esta vacía borramos la fila
         If .Text = Chr(13) & Chr(7) Then
            fila.Delete
         End If
        End With
    Next fila

End Sub
```

¿Por cierto el procedimiento no se debería llamar eliminar_filas() ?